# Finit element modelling of rigid bodies and machining

Tags: computational-physics

I would like to computer model of material machining. Is finite element metod suitable for this?

I am imagining 3D grid of voxels, which are tracking matter properties across space. Is this correct idea?

What are correct terms for this to google for? Are there any software packages for this?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to model?